# Initialize a c-string in C++11?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

How do I initialize a c-string in C++11?

I tried:

```
char* foo = {"bar"};
```

but I get:

```
ISO C++11 does not allow conversion from string literal to 'char *
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it has to be pointer to `const`:

```
const char* foo = "bar";
```

Before C++11, you could make `foo` simply `char*`, even though that was deprecated since C++03. But C++11 removes the deprecation and simply makes it illegal.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is;

```
char const* foo = {"bar"};
//   ^^^^^ added const
```

The older C style (non `const`) was deprecated and now is removed from C++11.

Comment: char const or const char?

Comment: Either both are correct, the const can be before or after the char. It is just my preferred style.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thanks!